# How to remove Even numbered nodes from a singly linked list

Tags: c++, linked-list, nodes, delete-operator

So my task is to take prewritten code that generates/populates/prints/ destroys a singly linked list and add functions that count the even number of nodes.

The specified prototypes are

int countEven(node * head)
compute and return the number of nodes that are in the linear linked list

 int removeEven(node *& head)
remove all the nodes that contain an even number in the linear linked list and return the number of nodes removed

countEven was not a problem and is functioning correctly, however removeEven seems to work on random numbers

For example, main.cpp looks like so...

```
#include "list.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
node * head = NULL;
build(head);
display(head);

//PLEASE PUT YOUR CODE HERE to call the function assigned

cout << "The number of even nodes is " << countEven(head) << ".\n";

cout << "The number of even nodes removed was " << removeEven(head) << ".\n";

display(head);
destroy(head);

return 0;
}
```

and the function removeEven looks like so...

```
int removeEven(node *& head)
{
    node *current;
    node *trailCurrent;
    int currentData = 0;
    int numberOfItemsRemoved = 0;

    current = head;

    trailCurrent = NULL;

    while(current != NULL)
    {
        currentData = current->data;        

        if(currentData % 2 == 0)
        {

            if (head == NULL)
            cout << "Cannot delete from an empty list.\n";  
            else
            {
                if (head->data == currentData) //Node is in beginning of list
                {
                    current = head;
                    head = head->next;

                    delete current;
                    numberOfItemsRemoved++;
                }
                else
                {
                    trailCurrent->next = current->next;

                    delete current;
                    numberOfItemsRemoved++;
                }
            }
        }

        trailCurrent = current;
        current = current->next;
    }

return numberOfItemsRemoved;
}
```

The output is random since the build function seems to make random lists with random numbers but here is a sample

```
Here is the original list: 2 -> 51 -> 44 -> 46 -> 1 -> 49 -> 2 -> 53 -> 52 -> 2

This list contains 10 numbers of items
The number of even nodes is 6.
The number of even nodes removed was 6.


The resulting list is... 51 -> 31571024-> 1 -> 49 -> 53 -> 31571216

This list contains 6 number of items
The sum of all data is: 63142394
```

Valgrind is telling me there are invalid read and writes of size 8 which tells me that something is being written or read where it shouldn't. I don't think the case for a head node is the problem as the random number appears AFTER the first in the list, in which case I think the delete function is causing problems. Could anyone point out where I'm going wrong? I checked the other entries on deleting stuff from lists and my solution doesn't seem wrong. Thanks for the tips!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an example of a guiding principle that I follow, which is more often right than it is wrong: "when something looks too complicated, it's probably quite buggy".

This shouldn't be very complicated, with the right approach.

And the right approach, believe it or not, is not to try to keep the pointer to the current element being examined, but a pointer to the pointer to the current element, for the reasons that should become obvious:

```
int removeEven(node *& head)
{
    node **currentptr= &head;
    int numberOfItemsRemoved = 0;

    while (*currentptr)
    {
        if ( (*currentptr)->data % 2)  // Odd
        {
            currentptr = &(*currentptr)->next;
            continue;
        }

        // Remove a node with an even value

        node *p= *currentptr;
        *currentptr= p->next;
        delete p;

        numberOfItemsRemoved++;
    }

    return numberOfItemsRemoved;
}
```

Fairly certain this will handle all edge cases. Multiple consecutive nodes to remove, removing the first node in the list, the last, etc...

Comment: That works very well, thanks. Yes, I've found that complex programs rarely work as they should.

So you use a pointer to a pointer to avoid the risk of the pointers becoming corrupted?

Comment: I use a pointer to a pointer because this makes the overall logic much simpler. And because it's much simpler, there's less of a chance of introducing a bug that screws everything up. The pointers won't get corrupted due to random chance of some kind, which has more or less risk than an alternative approach. Either a given chunk of code is right, or it's wrong. And it's far likelier that a simple chunk of code will be right, than an over-complicated, tangled hairball. "The more you overthink the plumbing, the easier it is to stop up the drain."